# How can I launch (run) C:\Windows\notepad.`.exe` after I rename it to MSnotepad.`.exe`? 

Tags: windows-7, rename, notepad

On Windows 7 (32-bit) I want to

A. Replace notepad.exe with NoteTab Pro
   B. Still be able to run the original notepad program on occasion.

What I've done so far accomplishes goal A:

- Take ownership of the Microsoft installed copies of Notepad

  ```
  takeown /f C:\Windows\notepad.exe /D
  takeown /f C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe /D
  ```
- Grant Full Control to the Administrators group (of which I am a member)

  ```
  echo y | Icacls C:\Windows\notepad.exe /Grant Administrators:F
  echo y | Icacls C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe /Grant Administrators:F
  ```
- Copy the original notepad.exe to another name

  ```
  copy C:\Windows\notepad.exe C:\Windows\MSnotepad.exe
  copy C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe C:\Windows\system32\MSnotepad.exe
  ```
- Copy the NoteTab launcher EXE to Windows and Windows\System32

  ```
  echo y | copy "C:\Program Files\NoteTab Pro 6\NotePad.stb" C:\Windows\system32\notepad.exe
  echo y | copy "C:\Program Files\NoteTab Pro 6\NotePad.stb" C:\Windows\notepad.exe
  ```
- Create the INI files required by the NoteTab launcher

  ```
  echo [Application]>C:\Windows\system32\notepad.ini
  echo ExeName="C:\Program Files\NoteTab Pro 6\NotePro.exe">>C:\Windows\system32\notepad.ini
  echo.>>C:\Windows\system32\notepad.ini
  echo [Application]>C:\Windows\notepad.ini
  echo ExeName="C:\Program Files\NoteTab Pro 6\NotePro.exe">>C:\Windows\notepad.ini
  echo.>>C:\Windows\notepad.ini
  ```

When I attempt to launch either `C:\Windows\MSnotepad.exe` or `C:\Windows\system32\MSnotepad.exe` nothing happens and no error is in the Windows system or application logs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I've seen the original post date, I guess it have been solve since then...

Did you tried to launch MSNotePad from the Command Prompt or from the folder directly?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue on Windows 10. Launching from cmd prompt or Explorer silently fails (does nothing).

Comment: What does the `/D` at the end of each `takeown` command line do?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today (2022) on Windows 10.  This link ([What prevents copied/renamed/moved notepad.exe from running in some Windows editions?](https://superuser.com/questions/1214490/what-prevents-copied-renamed-moved-notepad-exe-from-running-in-some-windows-edit)) turned out to be spot on with what was wrong in my case.  Going into the `en-us\` folder in `C:\Windows\`, creating a copy of `notepad.exe.mui`, and renaming it to match my new executable name, allowed that .exe to run.